# Tab bar icons showing in simulator but not on App

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitabbaritem

In an app I published the tab bar titles appear fine, however 2 of the 3 icons don't appear, and I'm not sure why because they all have the same properties. I'm using the most recent version of xcode, below are pictures of the actual app and then the simulator.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Set the tab bar's `tintColor`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you need to do is go to the ACTUAL view controller that your storyboard reference is pointing to.
This is the "real" UITabBarItem. Set your properties there and you will see them show when you run the app.

Comment: Those real UITabBarItem controls are what I used, and when I run the app on the xcode simulator it shows them perfectly, but the problem is that the actual version released to the apple App Store still doesn't show them.